# Best way to display credits from an android application

Tags: android, android-activity

**GOAL**
Hi,    I plan to include in all my aps a "credits" button that will display my logo, URL, etc.

**PREFERRED SOLUTION**
In order to be more effective I would like to have it as an independent app, so that if I later modify it, all the apps calling it would get updated to the same credits display, instead of modifying each of them.

**ALTERNATIVES**
**(a)** Of course the easy solution is to copy it within each of my apps and update manually each of them. I think this is not so effective when the number grows.
**(b)** Having a kind of external resource like a mobile adapted webpage which would always be called. I would only need to change it. But I open then the workfield out of android.

My first idea is to have to define it as an independent activity and get it called from each of the apps.
I have **two related questions**:
  1. How do I ensure this "credits" activity gets installed with an application (is there a kind of dependency which can be defined?)
  2. Is this a reasonable way of doing it within Android context?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if it can be done: you could create a CreditsActivity in an Android Library Project, reference it in your apps and add it in the manifest with its full name. (anyway the great advantage of option B is that it doesn't require an upgrade through the market)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I shall check what seems more economic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> PREFERRED SOLUTION In order to be more effective I would like to have it as an independent app, so that if I later modify it, all the apps calling it would get updated to the same credits display, instead of modifying each of them.

No user will download this, so do not bother writing it.

> 1. How do I ensure this "credits" activity gets installed with an application (is there a kind of dependency which can be defined?)

There is no way to accomplish this.

> 1. Is this a reasonable way of doing it within Android context?

No. As @bigstones suggests, use an Android library project.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I shall see what is more economic.